# How to compare form input data to database data in a custom codeigniter form validator?

Tags: php, database, forms, codeigniter, validation

Edit: Some naming had been mixed up in my attempts to solve it myself. I've fixed the callback etc naming and the same error persists.

I am attempting to create a login page for my codeigniter website. I already have a registration page that correctly inputs usernames and passwords in to a "users" table. I am having issues understanding the syntax of creating the functions needed for custom form validators.

My error is "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name" for the password and username custom validators.

Here is the relevant part of the controller "login_ctrl"

```
    class login_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('login_mdl');
}
function index() {

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

//Validating Name Field
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|callback_userCorrect');

//Validating Password Field 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_passwordCorrect');

//variables to pass form input
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password'); 

//reload login page if validation fails
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$this->load->view('login');
} else {
//functions for custom validation
function userCorrect($username) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //the loads the model that contains the function to compare input to database data
    $userExists = $this->login_mdl->userExists($username);

    if ($userExists) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
           'userCorrect', 'correct user.'
    );
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message(
            'userCorrect', 'not a valid user name.'
        ); 
        return false;
    }
}
function passwordCorrect($password) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $passwordExists = $this->login_mdl->passwordCorrect($password);

    if ($passwordExists) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('passwordCorrect', 'correct password.');
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('passwordCorrect', 'invalid password.'); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the corresponding view "login"

```
<?php echo form_open('login_ctrl'); ?>
<h1>Login</h1><hr/>
<?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo form_label('User Name :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('username'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_label('Password :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('password'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password')); ?><br />

<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?><br/>
```

Finally, this is the corresponding model "login_mdl" (I think the issue might be in this guy).

```
<?php
class login_mdl extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function userExists($username) {
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function passwordCorrect($password) {
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->row();
    return $result->password;

    if ('password' == $password) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
?>
```

I think my issue is related to the db calls and if statements but I've been reading documentation and failing at fixing this for hours so a new pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your fieldname on your costume rules function is same as your function callback. So, it’s should be like this :

```
  $this->form_validation->set_message(
           'userCorrect', 'correct user.'
```

Do same thing on your other function.